# label for package: fancyvrb

Tags: cross-referencing, sourcecode, fancyvrb

I have a latex code for a computer program code like as specified in [here](http://techlogbook.wordpress.com/2008/08/29/writing-computer-or-programming-code-in-latex/). I want to write a label to this code. I searched for it but was unable to find how to add label for the source code. Any help will be great!

---

*Cite from linked source, contents of link as of 2013-03-20 20:53:13:*

> To write a code in latex, you can use `\begin{verbatim}` `\end{verbatim}` environment. A similar approach is by doing this
>
> ```
> \usepackage{fancyvrb}
> \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}
> \DefineVerbatimEnvironment{example}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small}
> ```
>
> and then you can type your code in the body
>
> ```
> \begin{code}
> c+=1;
> \end{code}
> ```

Comment: I think I didn't understand properly. But `listings` may a worth try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean a TeX label, which you can reference elsewhere in the document with `\ref`?  One way is to use the `listings` package instead of fancyvrb.  Then, you can include your code in the document like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Cool code},label=cool]
c+=1;
\end{lstlisting}
```

As you would expect, the `caption` option provides a caption under the code listing (à la "Listing 1: Cool code"), and the label option provides a label which can be referenced like `\ref{cool}`.  A caption must be provided for the label to work, at least in my installation.

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Cool code},label=cool]
c+=1;
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Wow},label=wow]
c-=1;
\end{lstlisting}
As you can see in Listing~\ref{cool}, we can increment variables.
Having thought better of it, Listing~\ref{wow} allows us to retreat.
\end{document}
```

---

If, instead, you wish to reference a particular line number of a code listing, you can stick with the `fancyvrb` package and do something like this example from the fancyvrb documentation:

```
\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\},numbers=left,numbersep=2pt]
First verbatim line.
Second line.\label{vrb:Important}
Third verbatim line.
\end{Verbatim}

As I previously showed in 
line~\ref{vrb:Important}, it is...
```

You could make this simple to use by including the options in your `\DeclareVerbatimEnvironment` command, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{code}{Verbatim}{fontsize=\small,commandchars=\\\{\},numbers=left,numbersep=2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{code}
c+=1;\label{cool}
c-=1;\label{wow}
\end{code}
As you can see on Line~\ref{cool}, we can increment variables.
Having thought better of it, Line~\ref{wow} allows us to retreat.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Since it is tagged with [tag:cross-refencing] I think you are right.

Comment: Hey, with your edit you stole my answer !!! ;-) The label could, of course, also set in the first place of `fancyvrb`, and so the functionality should be very similar to `listings` then.